# NullPointerException when calling a mocked method

Tags: mockito

For this class definition:

```
@Service("customer-profile-service")
public class CustomerProfileService {
    CustomerProfileRepository customerProfileRepository;

    public CustomerProfileService(CustomerProfileRepository customerProfileRepository){
        this.customerProfileRepository = customerProfileRepository;
    }

    public CustomerProfile getCustomerProfile(RestConsumerRequest< MortgPointsFulfillRequest > consumerRequest) {

        RestConnectorResponse<RestConsumerResponse<CustomerProfile>> restConnectorResponseC1 = customerProfileRepository.customerProfileLookup(consumerRequest);        <- NullPointerException
        ...
    }
```

I wrote a testcase:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class CustomerProfileServiceTest {
    @Mock
    CustomerProfile customerProfile;

    @Mock
    RestConsumerRequest restConsumerRequest;

    @Mock
    CustomerProfileRepository customerProfileRepository;

    @Mock
    RestConnectorResponse<RestConsumerResponse<CustomerProfile>> restConnectorResponseC1;

    @Spy
    CustomerProfileService customerProfileService = new CustomerProfileService(customerProfileRepository);

    @Test
    public void getCustomerProfileTest() {
        doReturn(restConnectorResponseC1).when(customerProfileRepository).customerProfileLookup(restConsumerRequest);
        customerProfileService.getCustomerProfile(restConsumerRequest);
        Mockito.verify(customerProfileRepository, times(1)).customerProfileLookup(any());
    }
}
```

It complains NullPointerException at the above location (please scroll to the right).
Aren't all mock objects null? since customerProfileRepository is mocked, it should behave as so, right?

Could anyone tell me why and how to fix?

Comment: Did you [initialize the mocks](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations.html)?

Comment: The MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this) is deprecate. I added it anyways, but the same issue persisted.

Comment: Right. The docs tell you to use `openMocks()` instead. Did you try that? And if so, where did you add it. It has to be called before the test runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CustomerProfileService` will be initialized before the mocks are created, therefore, the repository will be null. To solve this, you can use the `@InjectMocks` annotation instead of `= new CustomerProfileService(customerProfileRepository);`

Alternatively, you can manually create the spied service in the before/beforeEach block:

```java
@BeforeEach
void beforeEach() {
    this.customerProfileService = spy(new CustomerProfileService(customerProfileRepository));
}
```